# Convert datetime to date view page in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date

[image]

I have this image, look at the line  `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.order_date)</td>`. My database value is date. In Visual is datetime but I want to convert datetime to date. When I view list I don't want to see `mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00`. I just want to see `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I tried to use `.toshorttimestring()` but it's not working

Comment: Did you try ToShortDateString() as opposed to ToShortTimeString? If so and it failed, how did it fail?

Comment: Please post your code here, not an image.

Comment: Add a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]` attribute to your `order_date` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToString and add appropriate formatting.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.order_date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```